# nodejs server not giving success status in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I want to use jenkins to run a nodejs project. All is going well except I do not see any success status in jenkins job.

I started the server with npm install & npm start command in jenkins. It starts the server, but does not give build success, as a result, I can not start other jobs which depends on the build success of the node server & when a new commit arrives, jenkins detects it but the job does not restart rather remains at pending status as the original job is running.

I am new to jenkins. can anyone suggest anything for that??

Comment: What is the exact cause of the failure? Could you append the log snipped of the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the execution of your js script is hanging your build, try using a & after to send it to background:

```
npm install
npm start &
```

Also note that running `npm start` from a Jenkins job will spawn a new process and [Jenkins will kill the jobs spawned during a build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller), That is a problem if you want this process to remain as a daemon.

To avoid that you need to to provide a flag right before your command:

`BUILD_ID=dontKillMe npm start &`

You haven't been specific about all the steps in your job pipeline but I imagine that you try to perform some post-build operation after your first job's build so finding out that your process is not running causing will cause failure in subsequent jobs.

Also, try using [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). It will ensure that your script is running continuously until you stop it, with it you can start your application like this:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe forever start yourApp.js
```

Comment: yes, I need to run some test script invoking rake on the web server that is run by the node project.
I have already used npm start &, it gives build success, but the server not started.
According to your suggestion I have also tried BUILD_ID=dontKillMe npm start &; but it does not work.

Comment: @tasin_megamind can you show us the script line you invoke when you're running the `npm start`? this is inside your packages.json file.

Comment: that works now with forever.
that is really helpful.

Comment: @tasin_megamind great!! Could you accept my answer then? :)

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**: It seems you nodejs server is not running on jenkins after execution, you have couple of **Solutions** that were investigated and got tested:

Option 1 - recommended: **run a background process on Jenkins** that keeping alive using *dontKillMe* flag and *nuhup* unix command in BUILD_ID parameter.

> From documentation:  A convenient way to achieve that is to change the environment variable BUILD_ID which Jenkins's ProcessTreeKiller is looking for. This will cause Jenkins to assume that your daemon is not spawned by the Jenkins build.
>
> **nohup** is a POSIX command to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. The HUP
>   signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes
>   of logout.

```
cd <yourApp>
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup npm start &
```

Option 2. using node.js external package such as **forever** or **pm2**

- PM2 is a daemon process manager that will help you manage and keep your application online 24/7 - [link](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)
- forever - A simple CLI tool for ensuring that a given script runs continuously (i.e. forever) - [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

forever example (installed locally):

```
cd <yourApp>
npm install forever
./node_modules/forever/bin/forever start -c "npm start"
```

pm2 example (installed globally):

```
npm install pm2 -g
cd <yourApp>
pm2 start scripts/start.js
```

**Testing:** Afterwards, can verify your server is up running using bash script commands:

```
# check process
ps -ef | grep node

# check connectivity in server port
telnet localhost <yourNodeJSPortRunning>
```

**P.S** sometimes some interrupted signals can cause issues in your `start.js` script and terminate the node process, try avoiding this - for example:

```
     ['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'].forEach(function(sig) {
      process.on(sig, function() {
        devServer.close();
        process.exit();
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err && err.message) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

After removing this piece of code it worked correctly, the process is on air as long as the machine is up.