# Deploying Nodejs application to Ec2 instance through Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I am trying to deploy my nodejs application to Amazon Ec2 instance through Jenkins. I tried with the following  two commands in Build step

`node server.js`  ==> application is deploying and terminating immediately.

`node server.js &`  ==> application is not deploying but build is success

Anyone, please help me with this.

Comment: I got answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039123/nodejs-server-not-giving-success-status-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/25406037/13683375

> Actually, by default, Jenkins has a feature called ProcessTreeKiller which is responsible to make sure there are no processes left running after the job execution.

[Unable to run nohup command from jenkins as a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341545/unable-to-run-nohup-command-from-jenkins-as-a-background-process) also has some related answers.

You may consider using `nohup` like so: `nohup node server.js &`